# Worklight 6.1: device.platform returns "null" on Windows RT 8.1

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We have develop a hybrid app using worklight 6.1 and dojo 1.9.1.

When we run the app on Windows RT 8.1 (Microsoft Surface tab), device.platform return "null" instead of OS name.
This works fine on Windows 8.1 Enterprise, Android and iOS.

Comment: Why don't you give a try in Worklight 6.2?

Answer (score 0):

Worklight 6.1 uses Cordova 3.1.
[Per the Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html), it seems Windows RT and Windows 8 are covered under the same umbrella, so this may be a bug in Cordova... requires some investigation.

```
Supported Platforms

Android
BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher)
iOS
Tizen
Windows Phone 7 and 8
Windows 8
```

Comment: I've sent a note to the Cordova team to verify the above.